# Error in Eclipse web.xml on empty project

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets, tomcat10

Can anyone help me?
I'm creating a new Dynamic Web Project on Eclipse 2021-06 with Apache Tomacat 10.
I'm always receving errors in web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" 
            xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>01Test</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Have marks on:

- version="2.5
- 

I receive the following errors
[image]

How can i solve??? I tried downloading Tomcat form website and through Eclipse... With Web module 4 and 5... but still have this problem...

Comment: Please open a bug report for this error in the generated deployment descriptor file.

Comment: Where did you get the `id` element in the `web-app` element?  I can't find a reference to that anywhere and I don't believe it's valid.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse validates the `web.xml` file against the provided schema:

```
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd
```

that schema requires the `version` attribute to be `2.4`. If you set it to the correct value `2.4` the error will disappear. Also Servlet 2.4 didn't have a `<display-name>` tag, hence the second *"error"*.

Since Tomcat 5.5 (which supported Servlet 2.4) is long gone, you should change the schema of your `web.xml` to either:

- Servlet 3.1, corresponding to the oldest version of Tomcat that didn't reach end-of-life (Tomcat 8.5):

  ```xml
  <web-app
      xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
      version="3.1">
  ```
- Servlet 4.0, corresponding to the last version ever under the Java EE name:

  ```xml
  <web-app
      xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
      version="4.0">
  ```
- Servlet 5.0, corresponding to Tomcat 10:

  ```xml
  <web-app
      xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
      version="5.0">
  ```

and set the version of the *"Dynamic Web Module"* facet accordingly. This way Eclipse will provide you with completion suggestions for the elements that were introduced in those specifications.

**Remark:** Maybe it has been corrected since, but Eclipse 2021-03 had still some quirks in the support of Tomcat 10 and Jakarta EE 9. E.g. it didn't allow to deploy a Servlet 5.0 project on Tomcat 10, it worked only with Servlet 4.0 projects and older.

You need also to be aware, that due to the migration from the `javax.*` to the `jakarta.*` namespace, your project will not work on older versions of Tomcat.

Comment: If you are seeing quirks 2021-06, please open bug reports for them.

Comment: @nitind: sorry, that would of course be the correct thing to do. But the temptation to just walk around those bugs instead of helping fixing them is great. :-)